# How to do CSS box-shadow in elm-css?

Tags: css, elm

Does anyone know how to create a `box-shadow` like this one:

```
box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

in [`elm-css`](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css)?

I tried this:

```
boxShadow (px 0) (px 4) (px 9) (px -4) (rgba 0 0 0 0.75)
```

without any luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used elm-css, but looking through documentation gave me this:

```
boxShadow5 (px 0) (px 4) (px 9) (px -4) (rgba 0 0 0 0.75)
```

Source: https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/blob/master/src/Css.elm